# Symfony 3 форма

Tags: form, symfony3, doctrine

Есть сущность "Каталог", у которой отношение `Many-To-One` с сущностью "Шаблон".
То есть при создании Каталога, нужно выбрать из списка один из уже существующих Шаблонов.

Как сделать, чтобы при получении данных с формы, я также получал объект Шаблон, а не просто его имя:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($catalog)
             ->add('template', ChoiceType::class, array('label' => 'Шаблон', 'choices' => $templates_form))
             ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Сохранить'))
             ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $catalog = $form->getData();
            // И хочу сделать сразу так
            $em->persist($catalog);
            $em->flush();
```

Массив `$templates_form` - сейчас в формате `{'template_name' => 'template_id'}`

Answer (score 1):

Если я тебя правильно понял то ты хочешь получить данные c формы в виде объекта. Тогда тебе нужно тип формы поменять с choices на Entity.
[Ссылка на документацию](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)